# Return List <int[]> containing all permutations of a given array

Tags: java, algorithm, permutation

Given an int[] {2, 8, 10} . I need to return all the permutations of this array in a list. But when I try to add them to a list it returns me {2, 8, 10} over and over again.

Also If I print the permutations , it gives me correct result. I have commented the system.out statement below in my code.Adding in the list (ALL_PERMUTATIONS) and returning it doesn't seem to be working. Can anyone point out what is going wrong

```
public class Permutation {
private static final List<int[]> ALL_PERMUTATIONS = new ArrayList<int[]>();

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] arrayOfIntegers = {2, 8, 10};
    int start = 0;
    int length = arrayOfIntegers.length - 1;
    Permutation permutation = new Permutation();

    List<int[]> allPermutations = permutation.generatePermutations1(arrayOfIntegers,start,length);


    for (int[] permutation: allPermutations) 
    {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(permutation));
    }

    part2All.generatePermutations(arrayOfBreaks, start, length);
}


private List<int[]> generatePermutations1(int[] arrayOfIntegers, int start, int length) {
    if (start == length) 
    {
        ALL_PERMUTATIONS.add(arrayOfIntegers);
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayOfIntegers));
    } else {
        for (int i = start; i <= length; i++) {
            int tempStorage = arrayOfIntegers[start];
            arrayOfIntegers[start] = arrayOfIntegers[i];
            arrayOfIntegers[i] = tempStorage;

            generatePermutations1(arrayOfIntegers, start + 1, length);

            tempStorage = arrayOfIntegers[start];
            arrayOfIntegers[start] = arrayOfIntegers[i];
            arrayOfIntegers[i] = tempStorage;
        }
    }
    return (ALL_PERMUTATIONS);
}
```

Actual Result:
[2, 8, 10]

[2, 8, 10]

[2, 8, 10]

[2, 8, 10]

[2, 8, 10]

[2, 8, 10]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    ALL_PERMUTATIONS.add(arrayOfIntegers);
    //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayOfIntegers));
```

when you add the array to the list, it is correct, but all you add into the list are the same array, so after added, you have modify the array to the original status.
you can have a try to modify

```
    ALL_PERMUTATIONS.add(arrayOfIntegers);
```

to

```
    ALL_PERMUTATIONS.add(Arrays.copyOf(arrayOfIntegers, arrayOfIntegers.length));
```

Comment: Yes it worked now !! But I still did not get it why?

Comment: your code is like change the content of array then add the array to the list then reset the content of array, but the array in the list is just the array you have reset, they are same one. the list just save a reference of the array. so all the array in the list is the original array

Answer (score 0):

In the `for` loop of your `generatePermutations1` method you're overwriting the same array for each permutation you generate. You should create a new one for each such permutation:

```
private List<int[]> generatePermutations1(int[] arrayOfIntegers, int start, int length) {
    if (start == length) 
    {
        ALL_PERMUTATIONS.add(arrayOfIntegers);
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayOfIntegers));
    } else {
        for (int i = start; i <= length; i++) {
            // New array generated here:
            int[] resultArray = Arrays.copyOf(arrayOfIntegers, arrayOfIntegers.length]; 

            int tempStorage = resultArray[start];
            resultArray[start] = resultArray[i];
            resultArray[i] = tempStorage;

            generatePermutations1(resultArray, start + 1, length);

            tempStorage = resultArray[start];
            resultArray[start] = resultArray[i];
            resultArray[i] = tempStorage;
        }
    }
    return (ALL_PERMUTATIONS);
}
```

Comment: But resultArray doesn't have any values, its an empty array. How will it then perform the swaps ? It gives me : [0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0] 
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]

Comment: @user16666 umm, yeah... that was stupid on my part. You should generate the new array as a copy of the old one, using `Arrays.copyOf` - see edited answer.